# Sanitzing input on form submit with PHP

Tags: php, escaping

I was hacking around this morning and wanting to use automatically generate safe-to-use variables from `$_POST`. Probably not the best use of `extract()` and `compact()`, but `extract()` allowed me to prefix variable names and `compact(explode())` seemed like a neat way to stick everything back into an array after being prefixed.

```
function sanitizeForm($formVars) {
    // prefix $_POST vars so attacker can't try and guess existing
    extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'form');
    // put the form variables back into an array
    $inputArray = compact(explode(' ', $formVars));
    $cleanInput = array();
    foreach($inputArray as $key => $value) {
        $cleanInput[$key] = htmlspecialchars($value);
    }
    return $cleanInput;
}
```

The test form I used simply posted `firstname`, `lastname`, and `comments`. Here's the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $test = sanitizeForm('form_firstname form_lastname form_comments');
    echo('<pre>');
    print_r($test);
    echo('</pre>');
}
```

Submitting 'test' for both `firstname` and `lastname` with the script in `comments`:

```
Array
(
    [form_firstname] => test
    [form_lastname] => test
    [form_comments] => <script>alert('xss')</script>
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should first ask yourself this: **Why am I sanitizing input in this way?**

Let's say I have a login form, and the user enters his credentials, an email and a password. The email will be queried against the database, to figure out the user's hashed password (You *are* hashing your passwords, **right?!**), and the password would be hashed, to be compared against that hash.

Both of those fields **will never be outputted to HTML**, the password is never kept in plain-text form for very long, and the username is queried against the database and then discarded. **So why should you escape them for HTML?**

---

Sanitizing (or more accurately named, **Escaping**), contrary to popular belief **should not** be done when you receive your input. It should be done **right before you output it**. Because at the time you receive your input, you have no idea where it's going to be used. It could be outputted to HTML (in which case it needs `htmlspecialchars()`), it could be outputted to JSON for an AJAX response (in which case it needs `json_encode()`), it could be stored in the database (in which case it needs **prepared statements**).

The general rule is: **You escape as late as possible**. HTML strings should be escaped right before they get echoed onto an HTML page.

---

What you *should* be doing when receiving your input, and as early as possible, is **validating** the input, i.e. **making sure the input matched what you expect in format, and in business logic**. Format means "This is a valid email address", and business logic means "This comment that the user is trying to edit, really belongs to him".